# Generating random points along network using ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, vba, random

How do I generate some random points along a network?

I am trying to do it with ArcObjects in the VBA environment.

Answer (score 2):

If you have either an ArcInfo, 3D Analyst, or Spatial Analyst license you could use the [Create Random Points (Data Management)](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000002r000000) tool to create random points along line features.

You can [call geoprocessing tools from VBA](http://resources.arcgis.com/CONTENT/kbase?fa=articleShow&d=31110), but you should know that [VBA is being deprecated](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/vba_desktop/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000133000000) and is not available in 10.1 and later. [This UC presentation](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/devsummit08/papers/migrating_vba-vb6_arcobjects_applications_to_net.pdf) suggests how you can migrate from VBA/VB6 to the .NET framework.